# How to set iFrame height and width using javascript based on the contents

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have an iFrame in my jsp page where in page load it should have height and width as 600 and 400 respectively. This iFrame contains some page having some forms in it, once the form is filled and submitted, it will redirected to a thank you page. At that time I need the height of the iFrame as 200(because the page contents are less and I need to reduce the white space in it). how to achieve this? I get n number of links in stack exchange itself but nothing is useful in this case.

Is there any way to check if the iFrame src url is changed? If so I can make a condition and do the below code to reduce the height.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoaded() {
  var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
  if(iFrameID) {
        iFrameID.height = "200";
        iFrameID.width = "400";
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        iFrameID.width = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
  }   
  }
</script>
```

The above function is working fine if i give it in iFrame page load but I need to set this only when I get the thank you page inside iFrame.

Request to kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like cookie.js (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for creating a helper cookie for each step in your iframe.

```
(function($) {

    $( '#submit-button').on( "click", function() {
        Cookies.set('isSubmitted', true);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Now you can check if the cookie is set and resize the iframe

```
(function($) {

  if(Cookies.get('isSubmitted') === true) {
      $('#iFrameID').height(200);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

After this you can delete this cookie

```
Cookies.remove('isSubmitted');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do iFrame url change check in the parent page like this:

```
function check(){
    $('#idIframe').load(function() {
        console.log("the iframe has changed");
    });
};

$("#idIframe").on("mouseenter",function(){
  window.setInterval(check, 100); // 100 ms
});
```